# How to write OrderedDicts into a file and read it back to a list?

Tags: python, list, file, arraylist, ordereddictionary

I have a function which returns `collections.OrderedDict()` which is a payload for http post.

I need to log offline data when http post fails, so I want to write all dicts into a file and read it back as a list, I know I can create a list and keep appending to the list, but the need is to write into a file and read back into a list,

Could some one please help me to resolve this problem, please suggest if there is a better idea to retrieve dict items as a list

Comment: Would you be happy to do it without using a file?

Comment: `list(dictionary.items()`

Comment: Thanks peter for reply, file write is mandatory as dicts could grow into tens of thousands and keeping a list isn't advised :(

Comment: hey chris, will i be able to append the file with new entries of dicts using pickle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert a list of dictionaries to a `json` and save it to a `.json` file.
Then, reading it will be a piece of cake.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
dic = OrderedDict()
dic['hello'] = 'what up'
dic_2 = OrderedDict()
dic_2['hey, second'] = 'Nothing is up'

with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    dictionaries = [dic, dic_2]
    f.write(json.dumps(dictionaries))
with open('file.json', 'r') as read_file:
    loaded_dictionaries = json.loads(read_file.read())
    print(loaded_dictionaries[0])
```

Outputs:

```
{'hello': 'what up'}
```

This will work cleanly as long as the dictionary key/values are any of these types: `dict, list, str, int, float, bool, None`.

Comment: Thanks nether for your response, the dict object keeps growing over time, whenever i am offline i want to dump the dicts into a file and once i am online , i want to send to server

Comment: Whenever you need to update it, simply open the file again, read the file so you get a `list` from it, append to the list, convert the list to json with `json.dumps(list)` and write it to a file.

Comment: i read it wrong all time by not changing list back to json, now i read the file back to list using json.loads and append the new dict and then write back using json.dumps , Finally when i need to pass the dict, i just read the whole file with json.loads and send it, your solution works great, thanks @Nether

Answer (score 2):

Use json for data serialization.

```
import json
import collections

d = collections.OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])

s = json.dumps(list(d.items()))
print(s)

value = json.loads(s)
print(value)
```

json serializes the object to a string `'[["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]'`. Then json can read the data back in to a python object.

json is very common and is used in many languages. Most web apis use json to help make their app RESTful.

Comment: thanks for your response, the dict keeps growing over time and i need to append file each time i get the dict object, please suggest if you have an alternative

Comment: I would have to see some code. If you have multiple dictionaries then call `dict.update(other_dict)` That will merge the dictionaries.